# C# .Net MVC and CA/Siteminder middleware

Tags: c#, jquery, siteminder

History: I have a tiny app that has lived on a linux web server for a while: html5/javascript/perl cgi scripts.  There is a sort of third party middle ware called Siteminder from CA that provides SSO services and it works fine.  In my case on the linux box there is a dir in the DOCROOT that holds the Public facing html, js & perl cgi scripts.  There is a different dir where the pages and scriots for the authorized content sits.  Siteminder is configured to be aware of this auth-dir and the request paths that contain that auth-dir element.

Siteminder is tied into Apache and observes the request stream and when it sees a request with a path element that it cares about it holds the in-bound request; redirects the visitor to a branded auth page; deals with the auth flow and then, if authenticated, sends the original request on through.  In this case the auth is tied to an AD group.  Again, this works.  My pages and code are totally unaware of the existence of Siteminder.

For reasons above my paygrade it has been decided to move the content from the linux box to an IIS server.  Convert everything to C# .Net MVC.  I am NOT a windows person but this is what is in my plate at the moment.

Our local Siteminder experts tell me that SM works exactly the same under IIS as linux.  That once I convert my code that it doesn't need to be aware of SM either... yet something is not working.

In my case, due to user interaction a modal popup appears in the Public section (HomeController) that holds a small form.  Clicking the submit button triggers a jQuery GET (I've also tried PUT, POST and a redirect) action to a method in the AuthController, a la:

```
    $.get({
        'url': "/Auth/AddNewData",
        'contentType': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        'dataType': "json",
        'traditional': true,
        'data': {
            'thing': myThing,
            'otherThing': myOtherThing
        }
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
        console.log("it worked");
    }).fail(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.dir(jqXhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

I am aware that there are .Net ways of stating the target url, please bear with me.

What I expect to happen is that if the visitor does not have the auth session cookie that Siteminder sets then they should be redirected to the SM auth flow and once authorized have this request complete.

Instead, what happens is that:

- I use the `get` method: it fires and I get a 302 "Object Moved" response.
- if I use the `post` method: it fires and I get a 200 Ok response but the returned payload is a small amount of html from SM saying that if I am not redirected to my destination shortly to press the button included in the form in that html. The jQuery `fail` promis fires though because it is expecting a JSON result, not html.
- if I use `put` nothing happens.
- I comment out my jQuery ajax call and just use a "location" redirect then SM will put up its challenge page; I can log in; and, the triggering request will be "continued" into a loop of length 3: it calls the page and fails with a 302 that seems to send the request back to SM where it is sent back to the target address to get a 302 then back to Sm then back to the target but it generates a 404 message.

I am deep in the weeds here.  Advice would be wonderful

Oh, PS: running this in debug mode on my desktop (no SM) works.  Running the Release version on the IIS dev server with SM is what fails.

**EDIT**

More info: after some additional siteminder config I started getting CORS violation messages.  I am setting CORS headers now but that changes nothing.  Siteminder seems to strip the CORS headers :/

Another thing I have noticed is that if i craft the failing GET request as a javascript `location.href=url + "?" + queryStringData` redirect everything works.  Current jquery is all but depreciating setting `async` to false so crafting a non-async version is more than I want to tackle at the moment.

The local siteminder folks will file a ticket soon I think.

**EDIT 2**

I have ended up with a hacky "fix".  I can not use standard GET, POST, PUT, etc methods to interact with the MVC methods because Siteminder is in the way.  I have added CORS headers and have tried JSONP, none of that works in this case.

I have to use "redirects" instead.  Setting `location.href = "/usr?thing=foo&bar=baz"` in the javascript functions then redirecting to the url as a result of the MVC methods.

This might be a Siteminder config issue.  The local Siteminder mavens have submitted a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Your question still isn't clear what the problem is with each of the bullets you listed. Is the GET behavior what you expect? A 302 is just a redirect, is it the redirect you expect?

For "POST", you are seeing the "post preservation" behavior. Its what SiteMinder does so that if your session has timed out in the middle of filling out a form, you don't lose your work. Post preservation is a configuration parameter in the "Agent Configuration Object" in SiteMinder. It sounds like your SM admins have configured the ACO differently for the IIS server than they did the Linux server.

PUT - nothing happens? You don't get any response at all, the connection just hangs?

Your last bullet, with the redirect loop, this looping typically indicates that your user is logged in (authenticated) but not authorized, which is a SiteMinder policy configuration issue (again it sounds like different policies are being applied to your IIS server than the Linux)

HTH!

-Richard